# How do devices know how to connect a server from a different network using SSH?

Tags: networking, ssh

A SOHO network exists with many devices on it including more then 1 server, several end clients and network switchs. Lets say the private IP address for a specific server is 192.168.0.10 we will say the public IP address for the whole network is 11.2.2.11. A device from a different location wants to connect to the specific server mentioned earlier using SSH from 141.10.2.2. With so many devices on the network 11.2.2.11 how does the computer know that 141.10.2.2 wants to communicate with the server at 192.168.0.10? Using putty as an example we know that SSH communicates on port 22, how would the computer know that we want to connect to 192.168.0.10 on the private network and not another one of the servers with SSH setup? Does the person on the private network need to setup SSH to work on different port numbers for each server that is expecting to be remoted into?

For some context i am currently trying to setup a basic Linux server on my own home network and I am confused as to how I would connect to my servers when I am on different networks. I plan to have more then one server and I intend to use virtual machines. I am learning and trying to figure out how i would connect to each server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should  use ssh port forwarding
let's say you want to connect to the port 22 of the 192.168.0.10 inside the private remote network .
use

```
ssh -L1337:192.168.0.10:22 user_remote_public@11.2.2.11
```

this will tell the 11.2.2.11 that you want to connect to the host 192.168.0.10 inside their private network on the ssh port .
now in order to establish the connection you should ssh on your localhost on port 1337 which will then be forwarded to the port 22 of the 192.168.0.10 inside remote private network

```
ssh user_remote_private@localhost -p 1337
```

Comment: Alright, this makes a lot more sense now.  the only thing I don't understand is "in order to establish the connection you should ssh on your localhost on port 1337" can you explain a bit more about this?

Comment: check this video ou ,it is very well explained : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JKrO5WABdoY&t=251s